# How to find object by multiple attributes in sahi for ruby

Tags: ruby, sahi

In Sahi controller, this works fine

```
_div({className:"/class.*/",id:"id"})
```

But I tried below in sahi for ruby, it always returns false.

```
@browser.div('{className:"/class.*/",id:"id"}').exists?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for now:

```
assert @browser.div(@browser.eval('({className:"class",id:"id"})')).exists
```

This will work.